# Hook before the file insert, before the file come on the server?

Tags: 7, hooks, files, uri

I want alter the URI's files before they are stocked in the server.
The file insert, I mean, everywhere/time a file is uploaded via Drupal (all insert file process, not only when an user add a file via a form)

Is it possible ?

An example : 
With drupal defaults settings, files ares stocked in the files directory (drupal/sites/default/files)

I want stock files in another directory (out of drupal main directory, by exemple in the directory /save/files)

And

I want to organize files like this : 
files/pictures/01_May
files/pictures/02_May
...
files/pictures/day_month 
(its an exemple for pictures, maybe there is another structure for the video etc..)

So, when the user or the drupal code (.module, via the drupal api) upload a file to the server I want automatically stock this file in the directory /save/files)
With the hook insert I can change the URI of the file, but during the hook insert the file is ulready uploaded in the server.

I'm looking for a way for move any files uploaded to the good directory before files are stocked in the server

Comment: I ran into a similar need some time ago, this might help you http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/118677/managed-file-validation-on-first-upload-only The file is uploaded to a temporary directory on the form then moved to the permanent directory upon submit. You should be able to change the filename during the validation before it is written permanently.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i'm looking for a way who the file comes directly to the target directory (not temp dir then final directory). Moreover, I want this new target directory get another files insert by user (files likes : css/jss compressed, files inserted via a custom module etc..)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: do you want to change the directory where the files are stored? Is it just for the files from that form or for all files (a global setting)?

Comment: I want change the directory where files are stored and that for all files (global settings). I want also change the structure of the store directory (have a date hierarchical directory structure for image files by example).

Comment: take a look at this page, which allows you to config the public and private directores: admin/config/media/file-system  Then when you define your image field, it should ask you where you want your images stored: public or private. This allows you some good flexibility there. Does this help?

Comment: thanks for answer, but I'm looking for a global way (every files who will be stocked in drupal database, image, text, video ...)

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you are trying to do. Image is handled differently than text... What do you mean by every file in the database : image, text, video... can you explain with an example

Comment: I edit my first post with an exemple :)

Comment: Thanks for the example. Does this [tutorial](http://www.rahulsingla.com/blog/2011/06/drupal-7-handling-file-uploads-and-moving-files-to-the-public-file-system) might get you started. Basically, you have to: 1) hook into every file upload - you should be able to use hook_form_alter and add a validation to any file upload 2)  then in your validation function overwrite the file name and upload path.

Comment: yes but the hook_form_alter works only when an user uploads a file from the website no ? what about files uploaded via drupal api from custom module ? (not by a form) there aren't a way for manage all uploaded files before they are stock in the server ?

Comment: Yes, the file upload is only a Form API function. So AFAIK there is no way to universally manage ALL files no matter where they come from.